# How do i use a copied CCS file on my new site

Tags: css

I have copied a ccs style sheet to be used on one of my top level site collections. I have the css in my style library. How do I get to to work for my new site/site collection

Comment: Please provide more details

Comment: why not copy the css in the 15 hive?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using On Premise SharePoint then you can deploy the CSS into the layout folder and it can be accessed by all Web Applications/Site Collections/Sites with ease

If you want to stick with Style Library, then you should form the URL to the file and LINK it in your Master Page accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If your site template is publishing site follow the mentioned steps below:

> Upload the CSS file to your style library then Go to Site Settings > Look and Feel > Design Manager > Publish and Apply design > Specify the path of CSS

these will allow all new sites to inherit the CSS
[image]